# Sessions diferentes para cada nível de acesso. É possível?

Tags: php, session

Estou criando um CRUD para o serviço, onde terei 3 niveis de acessos.

Níveis:

1. Administrador (Cadastra e exclui e edita as informações)
2. Colaborador (Apenas cadastras informações)
3. Usuario (Apenas lê as informações)

Adicionei um script onde ao logar, o sistema redireciona conforme o nível.

Parte do codigo que redireciona:

```
// O usuário está logado
        $_SESSION['logado']       = true;
        $_SESSION['nome_usuario'] = $fetch_usuario['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['usuario']      = $fetch_usuario['user'];
        $_SESSION['user_id']      = $fetch_usuario['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['nivel']      = $fetch_usuario['nivel'];
          if($_SESSION['nivel'] == "1"){
                header("Location: administrador.php");
            }elseif($_SESSION['nivel'] == "2"){
                header("Location: colaborador.php");
                }elseif($_SESSION['nivel'] == "3"){
                header("Location: usuario.php");
            }
```

Abaixo segue o código completo:

```
 VERIFICA_LOGIN.php
    
    <?php
    // Verifica se estamos conectados ao BD
    if ( ! isset( $conexao_pdo ) || ! is_object( $conexao_pdo ) ) {
        exit('Erro na conexão com o banco de dados.');
    }
    
    // Une $_SESSION e $POST para verificação
    if ( isset( $_POST ) && ! empty( $_POST ) ) {
        $dados_usuario = $_POST;
    } else {
        $dados_usuario = $_SESSION;
    }
    
    // Verifica se os campos de usuário e senha existem
    // E se não estão em branco
    if ( 
        isset ( $dados_usuario['usuario'] ) && 
        isset ( $dados_usuario['senha'] )   &&
      ! empty ( $dados_usuario['usuario'] ) &&
      ! empty ( $dados_usuario['senha'] ) 
    ) {
        // Faz a consulta do nome de usuário na base de dados
        $pdo_checa_user = $conexao_pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE user = ? LIMIT 1');
        $verifica_pdo = $pdo_checa_user->execute( array( $dados_usuario['usuario'] ) );
        
        // Verifica se a consulta foi realizada com sucesso
        if ( ! $verifica_pdo ) {
            $erro = $pdo_checa_user->errorInfo();
            exit( $erro[2] );
        }
          // Busca os dados da linha encontrada
        $fetch_usuario = $pdo_checa_user->fetch();
       // Verifica se a senha do usuário está correta
        if ( crypt( $dados_usuario['senha'], $fetch_usuario['user_password'] ) === $fetch_usuario['user_password'] ) {
            // O usuário está logado
            $_SESSION['logado']       = true;
            $_SESSION['nome_usuario'] = $fetch_usuario['user_name'];
            $_SESSION['usuario']      = $fetch_usuario['user'];
            $_SESSION['user_id']      = $fetch_usuario['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['nivel']      = $fetch_usuario['nivel'];
              if($_SESSION['nivel'] == "1"){
                    header("Location: administrador.php");
                }elseif($_SESSION['nivel'] == "2"){
                    header("Location: colaborador.php");
                    }elseif($_SESSION['nivel'] == "3"){
                    header("Location: usuario.php");
                }     
    
        } else {
            // Continua deslogado
            $_SESSION['logado']     = false;
            // Preenche o erro para o usuário
            $_SESSION['login_erro'] = 'Usuário ou senha inválidos';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

O problema é que quando eu logo como, por exemplo, como nível 3 (`usuario.php`), se eu apagar o `usuario.php` após a barra e colocar `administrador.php` ou `colaborador.php`, o sistema aceita.

Haveria uma maneira de barrar isto onde o usuário somente teria acesso na pagina respectiva ao seu nível de acesso?

Comment: Se a informação de acesso está na sessão, você não pode colocar em cada arquivo uma validação? Por exemplo, no arquivo `administrador.php` colocar algo como `if ($_SESSION['nivel'] != 1) die("Você não deveria estar aqui")`

Comment: Como Woss disse, seria melhor você verificar caso a caso cada arquivo e validar a partir dali, você pode até passar tudo que precisa na sessão, mas você precisaria tratar caso a caso do mesmo jeito no final, e por experiência própria, quanto mais enxuto você deixar esse sistema de níveis, mas seguro e fácil de fazer manutenção será no futuro.

Comment: Woss, coloquei conforme vc me orientou no cabeçalho das respectivas paginas, conforme o nível.
Deu certo. Agora cada usuário só consegue visualizar as paginas conforme seu nível de acesso.

Muito Obrigado pela orientação.